# Unsupervised training of sparse autoencoders in matlab

Tags: matlab, unsupervised-learning, autoencoder

I've tried to follow the example provided at mathworks for training a deep sparse autoencoder (4 layers), so i pre-trained the autoencoders separately and then stacked then into a deep network. When i try to finetune this network though, via the 
train(deepnet, InputDataset) 
instruction, the training stops instantly and i receive a "performance goals met" message. 
Is there a way to train and finetune a deep autoencoder network in an unsupervised manner in Matlab (no labels provided)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the "MSE" goal? Secondly, for fine tuning of network use a conventional back-propagation algorithm in supervised fashion.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site to share contact info or send private messages. Either share answers with everyone, or don't post.

Comment: I still don't know the answer, so nothing to share really. I ended up using different approaches (manual networks and layers).